# Image zoom with aligment

Tags: javascript, html, css

I needed help with this code from the W3Schools website, I would like to leave all the elements centered on the page. however when I centralize, the lens of the function is for the old position of the image.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_image_zoom

change the code, but I don't understand

When the image is centered the lens is outside of it. Like it's her old position

[Image Center, len incorret position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XVx3.png)

Resolved !!!

To resolve the situation, a div class="main" was created that encompasses all elements. In the css code, the settings that our friend Samar gave us were used. Thank you Samar.

[Imagem Solved!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcbZL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from what I understand, you want both the image and the zoom result to stay as they are, but be centred in the page?

If so, you need to use flexbox in your css like this:

```css
.img-zoom-container {
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

For more about flexbox, check out this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Yes correct, however the lens is outside the image, it should be moved together with the cursor in the image. Can you help me

Comment: Hi Rafael - ah I didn't notice that. I'm still learning JavaScript myself, so this might be above my skill level. I think the JavaScript is positioning the lens on the x and y axis and you need to edit that code?

Comment: Yes friend, in case if you remove the centralization it will be right. But the intention is to get everything centralized and the function to run normally and the lens inside the image.